# how to get ANT script to send an email when the build succeeds or fails?

Tags: email, ant

I have an ANT script that works fine.

When the build succeeds I'd like it to send an email that has "build succeeded" in the subject and include the build's console output as the email body.

When the build fails I'd like it to send an email that has "build failed" in the subject and include the build's console output as the email body.

Can someone tell me an easy way to do this?  Thanks!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ant mail logger](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#mail-logger) should be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1st answer is right

however, I build all my stuff with jenkins, hence use that to send emails
it integrates with ldap/active directory too